# Scala 2.12 logging compilation too verbosely in SBT 0.13.16

Tags: scala, sbt

Since updating to Scala 2.12, sbt logs immense amounts at `info` level on compilation, e.g.:

```
[info] /home/zoltan/workspace/reboot/juniqe/libs/db/src/main/scala/com/juniqe/db/slick/CmsBlockDao.scala:548: isomorphicType is not a valid implicit value for slick.ast.TypedType[slick.lifted.Rep[Short]] because:
[info] hasMatchingSymbol reported error: could not find implicit value for parameter iso: slick.lifted.Isomorphism[slick.lifted.Rep[Short],B]
[info]       block <- CmsBlock if block.blockId === blockId
[info]             ^
```

This looks like an error, but there is no compilation error, so I would like to silence these messages, because sometimes there's so many of them, my terminal overflows and I can't see the actual compilation errors.

How can I lower the logging level just for compilation (including test and integration test compilation)?

I've tried setting `logLevel in Compile := Level.Warn`, and `logLevel in Compile := Level.Warn`, but the messages are still there.

Setting `logLevel in Global := Level.Warn` does the trick, but I don't want to set it for the `Global` scope.

**Note**: This is a multi-project build, and I'm running `compile` from the root project.

Comment: Well, they sure look like compilation errors. Where are they coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out that all these errors appeared because a colleague had enabled the SBT flag `-Xlog-implicits`, which, according to SBT "Show[s] more info on why some implicits are not applicable". After removing this flag, the errors were gone.

Source: https://paulbutcher.com/2010/04/26/scala-compiler-advanced-options/